# Is it possible cypher dynamic label at @Query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using SDN 3.1.0.RELEASE.
And i trying danamic label query like

```
@Query("MATCH (n:{0}) RETURN n")
public List<SimpleArticle> findAllByDomain(String domain);
```

and give String parameter like SimpleArticle.class.getSimpleName()
when i launched test code, i met "SyntaxException At {0}"

so i change query to

```
@Query("MATCH (n:`{0}`) RETURN n")
```

this code is work but don't find Domain node.
result log is "Executing remote cypher query: MATCH (n:`{0}`) RETURN n params {0=SimpleArticle}"

so i run this cypher query in query broswer

```
MATCH (n:`SimpleArticle`) RETURN n ;
```

It works and find node.

Can i use dynamic labels in @Query ?

Comment: This question is a old version sdn.    
Now you can use 

` @Query("MATCH (movie:Movie {title={0}}) RETURN movie")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Labels cannot be parameterized. The rationale for this is that different labels might result in different query plans. A parameterized query is always using the same query plan - therefore it's not possible.

The only way to use "semi"-dynamic labels is by using string concatenation or by Cypher DSL.